# Unable to connect with EIA api url

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, get

I'm trying to retrieve data via EIA api url with the get method but unable to establish connection.

data URL= https://www.eia.gov/opendata/browser/petroleum/pri/spt?frequency=daily&data=value;&facets=series;&series=RWTC;&sortColumn=period;&sortDirection=desc;

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
call_eia = requests.get("https://api.eia.gov/v2/petroleum/pri/spt/data/?frequency=daily&data[0]=value&facets[series][]=RBRTE&sort[0][column]=period&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=0&length=5000")

print(call_eia)
```

currently getting <Response [403]> as output of print

Comment: Does print(call_eia.text) give anything useful?

Comment: @Carbon print(call_eia.text) gives the status of connection whether the connection is establish or not(200 is for successfully connected & 403 is for no connection found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting the URL passed to `requests.get` returns the self-explanatory message:

> API_KEY_MISSING
> No api_key was supplied. Please register for one at https://www.eia.gov/opendata/register.php

As described in [API Technical Documentation](https://www.eia.gov/opendata/documentation.php)
 you need to insert `api_key` parameter to the request:

```py
import requests

params = {'api_key': 'your_api_key'}
call_eia = requests.get("https://api.eia.gov/v2/petroleum/pri/spt/data/?frequency=daily&data[0]=value&facets[series][]=RBRTE&sort[0][column]=period&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=0&length=5000", params=params)

print(call_eia)
```

The documentation also describes how to obtain the API key.